# IndexError: string index out of range keeps coming up

Tags: python, appjar

I am learning the app Jar module so I decided to make an encoder but I keep getting this error and I don't get what it means. I have looked it up on here and it talks about indexes but I haven't got any I don't think. My code is below an I hope you can help.
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3j6y.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, noone is going to write code from screenshot - add code here, proper format it, etc. So everyone could understand what is the problem, how to reproduce it, and then it'll be possible to solve it.

Comment: Try to use  while counter < numLetters  , not while counter <= numLetters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that indexes in string in Python starts from `0` (index of the first symbol) and ends with `len(string) - 1` (index of last symbol). In your code, you have `counter <= numLetters`, so you have error trying access symbol with `counter` index while the maximum index is `counter - 1`,  use `counter < numLetters` instead.